# Misinterpretation of operator precedence when using ostream and ostringstream

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, ostream, ostringstream

The following code has different compile results. From the error message I'm receiving it seems there's a confusion about operators precedence `()` and `<<`. I can easily overcome this issue by using a function. However I would like to understand and to know:

a) Which compiler it's evaluating correctly the expression? MSVC2017 seems more logical to me.

b) Is there an workaround still using MACROs?

Full sample code I used.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define  EXPR_INSPECT(param_)\
         ( (std::ostringstream{} << "< " #param_ " [" << typeid(param_).name() << "] > : " << param_).str() )
#else
#define  EXPR_INSPECT(param_)\
         (param_)

#endif //NDEBUG
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   auto        ull_x    {99LLU};
   std::string string_x {"Checking..."};

   std::cout << EXPR_INSPECT(   ull_x) << std::endl;
   std::cout << EXPR_INSPECT(string_x) << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**MSVC2017** works perfectly!

G++ 8.2.0 (MSYS2/MINGW) issues the following ***error: 'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type' {aka 'class std::basic_ostream'} has no member named 'str'*** Attempts to call `str()` on `ostream` instead of `ostringstream`.

EDIT:

The problem here can also be reproduced [by clang using Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X7mYcode3jbrIF2u). Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   auto s = std::ostringstream{};
   decltype(((std::ostringstream{}) << "< "))::nothing;
   decltype((s << "< "))::nothing;
}
```

In wandbox, [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ay0sysKewbVwVDOU) found the second type `std::basic_ostream`, while the first type `std::basic_ostringstream`. That's very strange.

Comment: May I suggest you using less macros?

Comment: What do you mean by `there's a confusion about operators precedence`? `operator<<`s usually return `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @Nicky C. Suggestion accepted, but for purpose of the question it's irrelevant. With or without macros the behavior is the same. One compiler accepts it and works the other refuses it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the "MSVC2017 works perfectly" part. MSVC produces the same error as GCC.  https://godbolt.org/z/YjUfjz

Comment: I suspect that `NDEBUG` is defined in your VC++ target.

Comment: @molbdnilo Make sense. https://godbolt.org/z/wlWkDa

Comment: Simplified [mcve]: https://godbolt.org/z/tpum91

Comment: @NickyC Compiler Explorer might be buggy. I can actual reproduce OP's problem on my machine with clang. Wandbox also gives [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ay0sysKewbVwVDOU) *extremely bizarre* output. (Note in the return type becomes `std::basic_ostringstream` in one of the case)

Comment: @Nicky C. Well I'm actually using MSVC 2017(v141) and it works. Without any kind of optimization and /W3 level.

Comment: For what it's worth, I could not reproduce the problem using g++ 8.2.0 on my machine (with `-std=c++11`).  Could MSYS2/MINGW be pulling in some pre-C++11 headers?

Comment: clang's problem is due to this template function: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ostream#L1034, which includes all rvalues. I don't know whether it's standard conformant. Maybe your MSVC version also has similar highly-inclusive template function catching all rvalue.

Comment: In my very modest opinion there's no problem with CLANG or MSVC. g++ is not evaluating correctly the expression. If I put an expression between braces (no matter the operator I use) I expect it to be evaluated primarily and result used subsequently.